# unable to connect web service using java stubs input String output POJO

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have a Web Service(Called Connect), and another Web Service (Called Client). I am trying to call Connect WS through Client WS using generated stubs. The stubs are created using **wsdl2java** maven plugin.

And I can't print the error as well 
Checking through SOAPUI encountering following error to the corresponding request.

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-980NI68-1543911108884-98-1]</faultstring>
  </soap:Fault>
```

Here is a snippet of code that call the Web Service,Connect.
"request" is the parameter:

```
InterfaceClassService IFS = new InterfaceClassService();
wsdl.java2.InterfaceClass interfaceClass = IFS.getInterfaceClassPort();
Pojo pojo = interfaceClass.callThirdParty(request);
String response = pojo.getResponse();
return  response + " Client_WSDL2Java";
```

this is my POM.XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Camel Blueprint Quickstart</name>
  <description>Empty Camel Blueprint Example</description>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <properties>
    <camel.version>2.21.0.fuse-710018-redhat-00001</camel.version>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <version.maven-bundle-plugin>3.2.0</version.maven-bundle-plugin>
    <jboss.fuse.bom.version>7.1.0.fuse-710023-redhat-00001</jboss.fuse.bom.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.fuse</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.fuse.bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>org.apache.felix.fileinstall</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ga-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat GA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ea-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat EA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>jboss-ea-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat JBoss Early Access Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ga-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat GA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ea-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat EA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>jboss-ea-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat JBoss Early Access Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>client_wsdl2java</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>Empty Camel Blueprint Example [client_wsdl2java]</Bundle-Name></instructions></configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
              <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                  <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/myService.wsdl</wsdl>
                </wsdlOption>
              </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I run it as Local Camel Context it works fine and does the task,
but when I deploy it in the red hat fuse server 7.0 it gives me an error.
the bundle is deployed properly and the is started as well.
here is the error that i get from server logs:

> Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-DESKTOP-980NI68-1543911108884-98-2 on ExchangeId: ID-DESKTOP-980NI68-1543911108884-98-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-980NI68-1543911108884-98-1] Message History --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- RouteId ProcessorId Processor Elapsed (ms) [_route1 ] [_route1 ] [cxf://bean:client_wsdl2java ] [ 2] [_route1 ] [_log3 ] [log ] [ 2] [_route1 ] [_setBody1 ] [setBody[bean[ref:client_wsdl2java1 method:Client_callThirdParty]] ] [ 0] Stacktrace ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!
THANKS IN ADVANCE.

EDIT: Camel Route in blueprint DSL:

```
<camelContext
        id="camelContext-598b2e86-31b2-4224-8776-9eff5ac2d2254" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="_route1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="cxf:bean:orderEndpoint"/>
            <log id="_log4" message="log 2 ${body}"/>
            <setBody id="_setBody1">
                <method bean="OrderEndpoint1" method="Reply"/>
            </setBody>
            <transform id="_transform1">
                <simple>${body}</simple>
            </transform>
            <log id="_log2" message="log 3 ${body}"/>
        </route>
        <!-- test route -->
        <route id="_route2">
            <from id="_from2" uri="seda:incomingValue"/>
            <log id="_log1" message=" log seda Storing ${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

Comment: Since you get a Camel error, it would be helpful if you would post your Camel route into the question. Another valuable info would be if your webservice (Connect) receives a request or if your client fails before sending it.

Comment: The webservice(Client) can call the webservice(Connect) its just that I  cannot get the response of the websevice that i want. Getting an issue there.

Comment: Is the code in your question to call the Connect webservice implemented in the Bean `OrderEndpoint1` that is called in the route?

Comment: yes it is in that bean only

Comment: Do you know on what line of your Java code the error occurs? The error message mentions the `callThirdParty` method. Is the line `Pojo pojo = interfaceClass.callThirdParty(request);` successful or does the error occur on this line?

Comment: yes,error occurs on this line.

Comment: So is the webservice request failing (i.e. Fault or error response from the webservice)?

Comment: No, it is calling the webservice properly and getting the response. Its just that when i try to store it in the stub Pojo(of the derived class of the connect web service) its giving an error. There is no issue in the web service.

Comment: So the response is not of type `Pojo` then? Do you get any stacktrace on the client side? Does it work when you change the type to `Object` (just to test)?

Comment: the response is pojo. and i tried changing it to string it works but i want it to be pojo. no there is no stacktrace and dont know how to generate one from the code

Comment: When you change the response type from `Pojo` to `String` it works? But that would mean the effective response of the webservice cannot be converted to type `Pojo`. Have you logged the response out when it worked? Was it the response you expected from the webservice?

Comment: Yes the response is as I expected when the return is String. The web service Connect works fine if the return type is POJO and if I call it using SOAPUI it works fine. When  I call connect from client it is giving me error.

Comment: When the webservice returns an expected result but this cannot be converted to the expected type it could be a difference of the `Pojo` type between the server and the client. It sounds like the server generates a `Pojo` response that the client does not understand. How did you create the webservice, client and `Pojo` type? Generated from a WSDL or code-first?

Comment: generated from code first. I am using the generated stub Pojo, that is of the connect webservice. There is no client Pojo, you need to call using the generated stub pojo and take values from it.  If that is the case as you mentioned above what will be the solution?

Comment: Yes there is only one `Pojo` class but it exists in the webservice and in the client (different artifacts). Therefore there could be a difference if different versions of the `Pojo` class are in use. Can you make sure that the same version of the `Pojo` class is used in the webservice and the client?

Comment: How am i suppose to make sure that both have the same version. Could you help me out here?

Comment: I had to post this as answer even if it is perhaps not the problem because it would be unreadable in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there are different versions of the `Pojo` class in client and webservice. Check this, for example with the `javap` utility from a JDK.

```
javap -cp [path/to/jarfile] -v [your.package.Pojo]
```

Run this command for the JAR file of the webservice that contains the `Pojo` class and the JAR file of the client that contains the `Pojo` class. The command outputs a lot of stuff, you have to find the checksum of the class at the beginning.

```
Classfile path/to/whatever/Pojo.class
Last modified ...
MD5 checksum 99b7c66e2eb1ffe0a1ba39b65de7912d  << should be same for both Pojo classes
....
```

Compare the checksums of the Pojo classes in client and webservice. They should be same, if not, their version is different and this could be the reason the response cannot be converted to the `Pojo` type.

Comment: i tried it and found the following error:                                    
C:\Users\Lenovo>javap -cp C:\Users\Lenovo\eclipse-workspace\cxf2\target\shared.jar -v camelinaction.order.Pojo
Error: class not found: camelinaction.order.Pojo

C:\Users\Lenovo>

Comment: If you rename the JAR file to `shared.zip` and open it with a ZIP tool, do you find the class under the path `camelinaction/order/Pojo.class`? According to the error, the class `camelinaction.order.Pojo` does not exist in this JAR

Comment: Thanks, i got the issue, in the jar for connect the name of `pojo` is `POJO.class `and in the client side it is `Pojo.class` thats creating different checksum as well

Comment: Great, glad you found it!